# An example of a divergent double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to highlight to my friend that the change of order of summation/integrals should be done with care. In that regard, the conversation moved towards the following question.

> An example of a double summation with $f(m,n) > 0$ of the form
>   $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(m,n)$$ which diverges but $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} f(m,n)$$ converges for all $n$, and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(m,n)$$ converges for all $m$.

I am not able to construct an example immediately of my head.

Comment: Qiaochu's example is a good one for what you asked, but based on the intro text it would seem you want to ask for $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(m,n)$ to converge and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} f(m,n)$ to diverge.  Not that I have any suggestions for this.

Comment: @Ross: My intro is probably misguiding. I was explaining her the change of order of integration/summation and then along the discussion for some reason landed up on this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $f(m, n) = \delta_{mn}$ plus something very small.

Comment: I'm missing something.  What does "plus something very small" mean?  Why doesn't $f(m,n) = \delta_{mn}$ work by itself?

Comment: @Jason: the OP asked for $f(m, n)$ to be positive everywhere. (I'm not sure why.)

Comment: Ah, that'll teach me to read closer.  Thank you!